# Force jsonix to output xsi:type attribute

Tags: jsonix

According to the wiki page of Jsonix regarding its support for `xsi:type`:

> When marshalling, Jsonix checks, if the value has the same type as
>   declared in the property or element declaration

I'm wondering if there is a way to explicitly get Jsonix to generate that attribute? I was able to do that in another project by specifying the `TYPE_NAME` property, i.e.

```
  element: {
    TYPE_NAME: 'mapping.Element',
    xAttr1: '1',
    xAttr2: '2',
    content: 'some content',
  },
```

Now i'm doing some XML exports again but the same approach doesn't work any more, i.e. i get the correct xml but the `xsi:type` is missing. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7wav5bkL/) is a working fiddle using a stripped down version of my mappings, that shows how an item is unmarshalled with a type and then is being marshalled without one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, your unmarshalled `Title` has the type `Mappings.SomeType`, which matches your mappings. So Jsonix does not need to output `xsi:type` as there's a match.

If I understand you correctly, you want Jsonix to *always* output `xsi:type`. Not sure why you need this, but this is not supported OOTB.

You will probably need to patch Jsonix to get this. Here is where Jsonix decides whether to add `xsi:type` or not:

https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/blob/22b8800aa5acb645d614d01b858d0c8a25a3075f/scripts/src/main/javascript/org/hisrc/jsonix/Jsonix/Binding/Marshalls.js#L20

Since I don't quite see the need of forcing `xsi:type` output in general, I don't think this functionality should be included in Jsonix. So you'll probably end up with your own fork.

Comment: I needed the xsi:type for specific elements, and solved this by making the `type` of these elements `null` in the mapping files. Then whatever I put as `TYPE_NAME` is automatically put in `xsi:type`.